# How to replace * in sed

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to replace * with a number.

```
ifile.txt
2 3 4 *****
3 3 4 *****
1 2 1 *****
```

desire output

```
ofile.txt
2 3 4 999
3 3 4 999
1 2 1 999
```

I was trying with

```
sed -i 's/*****/999/g' ifile.txt
```

But not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **escape** the special character `*` using `\`, i.e.:

```
 sed -i 's/\*+/999/g' ifile.txt
```

Will match 1 or more `*` (`\*+`) and replace it with `999`

Comment: Why there are two `\\ ` inside single quoted (`'`) parameter?

Comment: This solution doesn't works on Ubuntu 15.04 because you need to add -r to enable extended rule set. As I already explained in my Answer below.

Comment: At least for GNU sed, you'd either have to escape the `+` with `\+` or use `sed -r`. Not sure about BSD sed.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sed -i 's/\*\*\*\*\*/999/g' ifile.txt
```

Because `*` is one of the most basic special characters in RE. See [POSIX BRE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) and directly from specification see [`QUOTED_CHAR`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_05_01).

Comment: This seems correct but it would be great if you could explain *why* it works, ie what the special meaning of `*` inside `sed` patterns is and how it can be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Because `*` is a special character (one of the most basic ones). For future reading [POSIX BRE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) and directly from specification see [`QUOTED_CHAR`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_05_01).

Comment: @5gon12eder If you're going to use `sed`, don't you think you should start by learning how regular expressions work? There's a tutorial at www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: @Barmar I absolutely think so. And precisely because of that, I don't think that Stack Overflow should be a pattern generator for those who didn't learn regular expressions. Either the question is worthwhile, then it should be answered with an explanation, or it is lazy and should be down-voted and eventually closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Without -r could not work**

If you need to replace exactly 5 * with 999.You can also use this:

```
sed -r 's/\*+/999/g' ifile.txt
```

In regular expressions *+* is used to match ***one or more*** consecutive repetition of

```
sed -r 's/\*{5}/999/g' ifile.txt
```

In regular expressions *{n}* is used to match exactly ***n*** consecutive repetition of

```
sed -r 's/\*{2,5}/999/g' ifile.txt
```

In regular expressions *{n,m}* is used to match ***minimum n and maximum m*** consecutive repetition of

**To be sure that your expression work as your expectation use -r, because sed standard expression (a reduced rule set) vary from unix/linux distribution, so use -r to be sure that all the regular expression rules will be applied (without the need of escaping +,{,},(,) special chars).**

Comment: Two remarks: `+` is not "any" number of repetitions, it's "one or more". `*` is "any number", including zero. And `-r` is not required, it just allows you to skip escaping some special characters: `sed 's/\(x.\+\{2,3\}\)/y/'` is equivalent to `sed -r 's/(x.+{2,3})/y/'`.

Comment: Yes you're right but I wrote this just because for example the above solution 's/\\*+/999/g' doesn't work on ubuntu without the -r option, but if you as best practise use the -r you're sure it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat t.awk 
function sgsub(r, t, s,    m, i, prefix, ans) { # substitutes `t' for
                                                # all occurence of the
                                                # string `r' in the
                                                # string `s'
    m = length(t)
    while (i = index(s, r)) {
       prefix  = substr(s, 1    , i-1)
       s       = substr(s, i + m     )
       ans     = ans prefix t
    }
    ans = ans s
    return ans
}

BEGIN {
    old = "*****"
    new = "99999"
}

{
    print sgsub(old, new, $0)
}
```

Usage:

```
echo '2 3 4 *****' | awk -f t.awk
awk -f t.awk infile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with gawk. The following code replaces the asterisks in fourth column with three nines.

```
gawk '{gsub(/*****/,"999",$4)}1' file 
        2 3 4 999
        3 3 4 999
        1 2 1 999
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.